# Unable to style custom button

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-button, android-styles

I'm trying to style a custom button - but most of the styles I've declared in `styles.xml` aren't applied.

```xml
<!-- styles.xml -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="selectableFlatButton">@style/SelectableFlatButton</item>
</style>

<style name="SelectableFlatButton" parent="FlatButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/bg_selectable_button_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/selectable_button_text_color</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/selectable_button_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="FlatButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
    <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">0dp</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/gray98</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:selectable">true</item>
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="iconGravity">textStart</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<!-- attrs.xml -->
<resources>
    <attr name="selectableFlatButton" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

The Button implementation. All it does is set default style.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.Button
import com.guyca.R


class SelectableFlatButton(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) : Button(context, attrs, R.attr.selectableFlatButton)
```

Usage in layout file:

```xml
<com.guyca.SelectableFlatButton
    android:id="@+id/selectButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="@string/select"
    app2:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_sweep_24dp" />
```

If instead if using my `SelectableFlatButton`, I use androids' `Button` and pass the style as `style="@style/SelectableFlatButton"` - it looks as expected.

It seems like the only style properties which work are `android:textAllCaps` and `android:textColor` - the rest have no effect on my Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a MaterialTheme you can extend a [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md):

```
class SelectableFlatButton(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) :
    MaterialButton(context, attrs, R.attr.selectableFlatButton)
```

Then define the default attribute style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
  <item name="selectableFlatButton">@style/SelectableFlatButton</item>
  ...
</style>
```

and:

```
  <!-- Custom -->
  <style name="FlatButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">0dp</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/...</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/....</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/....</item>
    <item name="android:insetTop">...</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">...</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTextAppearance.MaterialComponents</item>
    <item name="android:selectable">true</item>
    <item name="iconGravity">textStart</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/....</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTextAppearance.MaterialComponents" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  </style>

  <style name="SelectableFlatButton" parent="FlatButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/...</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/...</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

Using in your layout:

```
   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:icon="@drawable/...."
        style="@style/SelectableFlatButton"
        ../>


   <com.xxxx.SelectableFlatButton
        app:icon="@drawable/..."
        .../>
```

you have the same result.